# Why can't "node.js / Crawler" be installed on Windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js

I have Windows XP (32bits) and Windows 7 (64bits) but [node.js](http://www.nodejs.org) (Crawler) can't be installed on either Windows.

```
$ npm install crawler
```

It is sayings `O/S not supported` or something like that. I can only use it on Linux currently, But how to make it run on Window machines?

Comment: Maybe it needs POSIX system calls which are not available in windows? You could try cygwin or virtual machine to emulate?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the windows installer?  http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.18/node-v0.6.18.msi

The Complete download link for when the next version comes out: http://www.nodejs.org/#download